# Is there any way for stopping the GKE clusters at a specific time and restart at a specific time using cloud function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way for stopping the GCP GKE clusters and MySQL DB at a specific time and start at a specific time using the cloud function (With Python Script)

Comment: What do you mean by "stopping" the cluster? And MySQL DB is a managed Cloud SQL service or something else?

Comment: To save cost I want to pause my QA Kubernetes cluster(Make the node pool to 0) and the MySQL DB at a certain time automatically (9:30 PM IST it has to be paused and at 9:30 AM IST it has to be started automatically).

Answer (score 1):

You could use two scripts in two [Cloud Scheduler cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating) or another VM/host with a [crontab](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm) that use `gcloud` to switch the node pool between 0 and the original amount of nodes, and stop/start the Cloud SQL instance, with [container node-pools update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/update) and [sql instances patch](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance#start) respectively:

Stop job (run at 9:30 PM):

```
gcloud container node-pools update NODE_POOL_NAME --cluster=CLUSTER_NAME --zone=CLUSTER_ZONE_OR_REGION --min-nodes=0 --max-nodes=0
gcloud sql instances patch CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_NAME --zone=CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_ZONE --activation-policy=NEVER
```

Start job (run at 9:30 AM):

```
gcloud container node-pools update NODE_POOL_NAME --cluster=CLUSTER_NAME --zone=CLUSTER_ZONE_OR_REGION --min-nodes=NODE_POOL_NODES --max-nodes=NODE_POOL_NODES
gcloud sql instances patch CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_NAME --zone=CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_ZONE --activation-policy=ALWAYS
```